# Limitar el numero de datos a mostrar en una tabla con php

Tags: php, html5

```html
 <div class="table100-head">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr class="row100 head">
                  <th class="cell100 column1">Producto</th>
                  <th class="cell100 column2">Cliente</th>
                  <th class="cell100 column3">Vendedor</th>
                  <th class="cell100 column4">Monto de venta</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>

          <div class="table100-body js-pscroll">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <?php 
                $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ventas";
                                $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                while($datos=$result->fetch_array()){?>
                <tr class="row100 body">
                  <td class="cell100 column1"><?php echo $datos['producto']?></td>
                  <td class="cell100 column2"><?php echo $datos['nombre_comercial'];?></td>
                  <td class="cell100 column3"><?php echo $datos['vendedor2'];?></td>
                  <td class="cell100 column4">$<?php echo number_format($datos['total']);?></td>
                <?php 
                  }
                ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Tengo esta tabla con datos extraídos de mi base de datos, quiero poner una condición de que me muestre solo los últimos 5 registros que se hayan hecho, los mas recientes, alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Basta solo con limitar y ordenar tu consulta a la base de datos de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="table100-head">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="row100 head">
            <th class="cell100 column1">Producto</th>
            <th class="cell100 column2">Cliente</th>
            <th class="cell100 column3">Vendedor</th>
            <th class="cell100 column4">Monto de venta</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="table100-body js-pscroll">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
                $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ventas ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
                $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                while($datos=$result->fetch_array()){
            ?>
                <tr class="row100 body">
                <td class="cell100 column1"><?php echo $datos['producto']?></td>
                <td class="cell100 column2"><?php echo $datos['nombre_comercial'];?></td>
                <td class="cell100 column3"><?php echo $datos['vendedor2'];?></td>
                <td class="cell100 column4">$<?php echo number_format($datos['total']);?></td>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

si en tu tabla **ventas** tienes una columna como esto **created_at**, que significa fecha de creación del registro. Podrías hacer esto con la variable SQL.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ventas ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Pero si no tienes ese campo. Entonces podrías hacer un ORDER BY y LIMIT considerando el campo id, este si es auto incrementable.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ventas ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu consulta debes poner el top 5 y que se ordene de manera descendente, asumiendo que la primera columna de tu tabla en general sea un id

```
<div class="table100-head">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr class="row100 head">
                  <th class="cell100 column1">Producto</th>
                  <th class="cell100 column2">Cliente</th>
                  <th class="cell100 column3">Vendedor</th>
                  <th class="cell100 column4">Monto de venta</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>

          <div class="table100-body js-pscroll">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <?php 
                $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                $sql = "SELECT top 5 * FROM ventas order by 1 desc";
                                $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                while($datos=$result->fetch_array()){?>
                <tr class="row100 body">
                  <td class="cell100 column1"><?php echo $datos['producto']?></td>
                  <td class="cell100 column2"><?php echo $datos['nombre_comercial'];?></td>
                  <td class="cell100 column3"><?php echo $datos['vendedor2'];?></td>
                  <td class="cell100 column4">$<?php echo number_format($datos['total']);?></td>
                <?php 
                  }
                ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```